# Is there a plugin for vs code can paste like idea do?

Tags: visual-studio-code, plugins

for example , when I paste a mutiline html code , when i use idea , it automatic convert `"` to `\"` and auto add `\n` at end of a line.
I wonder if there is a plugin have the same ability to do this in vscode.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extension [Replace Rules](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bhughes339.replacerules)

Define this in your `settings.json`

```
  "replacerules.rules": {
    "Escape Double-Quote - Add \\n": {
      "find": ["\"", "$"],
      "replace": ["\\\"", "\\n"]
    }
  }
```

You can run the command: **Replace Rules: Run Replace Rule on clipboard and paste...** and select the rule.

Or add the following keybinding

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+f5", // or any other key combo
    "command": "replacerules.pasteAndReplace",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly",
    "args": {
        "ruleName": "Escape Double-Quote - Add \\n"
    }
}
```